# Output select * to txt file showing special characters - PostgreSQL on Windows

Tags: sql, windows, postgresql, special-characters, postgresql-9.3

I am using the copy command to dump the data of a table in PostgreSQL to a txt file. I run the following command in PSQL:

`\copy (select * from TableName) to 'C:\Database\bb.txt' with delimiter E'\t' null as '';`

now in the bb.txt file, **I see some special characters which are not there in the table itself**. The Database has been configured with UTF8 encoding.

For example: when I run the above mentioned copy query, if the special character shows up in the column with ID=5. If I run the same copy query with (select * from tablename where ID=5), the special char is not there:

`\copy (select * from TableName where ID=5) to 'C:\Database\bb.txt' with delimiter E'\t' null as '';`

This happens on a Windows machine. Can someone tell me where these special characters are coming from?

Comment: Please show some of the output in question. What "special characters"? What text editor are you using to open the file? What's the output of `SHOW client_encoding` in PostgreSQL?

Comment: Perhaps you're looking at the UTF-8 containing file with a editor, that doesn't understand UTF-8? Try specifying `ENCODING` option.

Comment: Checked the Client encoding. It shows as **WIN1252**. I am opening the unloaded txt file in Notepad++ where I see the special characters and Notepad++ supports UTF8 encoded files........ I unloaded this table to a text file using the COPY command. when I tried to reload the same txt file (Using COPY command), it failed and stated that there is some problem at (say) line 55. I opened the txt file and found out that it has a special character at line 55.